# React Production and Cookie Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I developed a react app and a express API. Everything were working correctly in localhost.

I moved my API to digitalocean droplet which is only IP address and it's HTTP.

When I use API from react app in development environment, it's working. It's getting cookies from API, sending them to API for authorization...

But, after I run `npm run build` on my react app for production and serve it on my local computer, It's stopped to send cookies to API and API stopped send cookies to react app anymore.

I set my API's IP as base url and credential true in index.js / react app

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

API cors settings in API

```
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}))
```

Axios login request (no cookies shows up after succesfull login)

```
await axios.post('/api/main/login', {form: form}).then(async resp => {

        if(resp.data == 'VALIDERR' || resp.data == 'CHECKERR') {

          setErrs({...errs, serverErrs: [resp.data]})
          setLoading(false)

        } else {

          setLoading(false)
          checkLogin()
          window.location.href = "/admin"

        }
   })
```

API's res.cookie for login request

```
res.cookie('auth', {token: token, name: user.name}).send('OK')
```

I hope someone have an idea what's going wrong after building react app.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar issue a few months ago. Here's how I solved it.

After running `npm build` and serving the production build locally, you must have noticed that It stops accepting cookies.

While building my app, I also had this exact issue on local. As I was working on a hobby project I decided to deploy my express-API-server to Heroku and my react-redux client on Netlify to check. (Note: Never push to production without adequate testing.)

Using the "edit this cookie" extension (can be also viewed using browser dev tools ), I found my cookies created at the API server domain, also the API server doesn't send over the cookies to my client. After a lot of research, I didn't get a concrete solution to why this issue persists.

Generally, I saw use `credentials: true` which seems to solve the issue in most cases (Where I saw no information regarding deployment/production enviornments) but It didn't seem to work for me however, I got some insights.

I decided to use a different approach to solve this. (JWTs)

My insights,

1. Check your `domain` and `sameSite` cookie options, if you're accessing from a client at another domain. (Here, I'm assuming you want to deploy your client somewhere else)

- You have to set `sameSite:false` for setting cookies at another domain.

2. If you're making a SPA, why not bundle the client together with the express server? So this solves the `CORS` and cookie domain issues.

   ```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(9000);
   ```
3. Use Token-based sessions (JWT)

- Agreed not ideal in every situation, but it helps for most scenarios.

I have built a few MERN-based apps, most deployed. Refer those to see how JWT is implemented in MERN.

- https://github.com/JaganKaartik/Shrynk.js
- https://github.com/JaganKaartik/Foodle

4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53566745/12408623

**References**

1. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53566745/12408623